# Driver for test database type [H2] is not available in the classpath

Tags: java, spring, security, h2

I am trying to run the the `Spring security web application`, but when web-app is being deployed I am getting below exception:

```
o.s.b.f.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/baeldung/spring/TestDbConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/baeldung/spring/TestDbConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Driver for test database type [H2] is not available in the classpath
    at o.s.b.f.s.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    ... 23 frames truncated
Caused by: o.s.b.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/baeldung/spring/TestDbConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Driver for test database type [H2] is not available in the classpath
    at o.s.b.f.s.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at o.s.b.f.s.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: o.s.b.f.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/baeldung/spring/TestDbConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Driver for test database type [H2] is not available in the classpath
    at o.s.b.f.s.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at o.s.b.f.s.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    ... 17 frames truncated
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

While i already added below in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.192</version>
        </dependency>
```

So this jar also available in classpath, but still getting above exception .

Can someone tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The jar will be in the classpath in your IDE.  Is it also deployed in your runtime environment?

Comment: @JimGarrison Generally all jar which added in classpath copied inside lib folder of the application when its creating war file.So this jar also should be copy.

Comment: How is the application packaged for deployment?

Comment: @JimGarrison By creating war file of the application

Comment: Have you confirmed that the WAR file actually contains the library, and it's at the correct path, and that the library jar file contains the class?

Comment: @JimGarrison I found the solution please have a look the answer section please let me know if you can add more on the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the solution which worked in my case i made following changes in `pom.xml` file i have to add `<scope>` with `h2` dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.192</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

> This scope is used to limit the transitivity of a dependency, and also
>   to affect the classpath used for various build tasks.

**runtime scope**

> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for
>   compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test
>   classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

Comment: Why did you change the version as well?

Comment: @ChristianMICHON Changed the version